# IBM Watson Dialog node response not coming

Tags: ibm-watson

I developed a chatbot which will call an action. That action is returning response and value is there in context variable but the value is not coming in chat dialog box. Instead, when i run again with a different input the previous response is coming in chat box.

Can anyone please help